# Binding with ListBox.SelectedItem fires only when item is chose by clicking outside

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I am using the following xaml to bind a TextBox to the selected item in a ListBox:

```
<Window x:Class="DataTemplateDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Margin="5">Contacts</TextBlock>
    <ListBox x:Name="LBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 0 0 3" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBox FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <TextBox FontSize="10" BorderThickness="0"
                        Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding Telephone}"/>
                    <TextBox FontStyle="Italic" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="10"
                        Background="Transparent" Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" Text="{Binding EditableContact.Name}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">Telephone Number</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" Text="{Binding EditableContact.Telephone}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Margin="5">Email Address</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" Text="{Binding EditableContact.Email}"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Margin="5">Selected Name</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Height="22" Text="{Binding ElementName=LBox, Path=SelectedItem.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Height="22" Width="50" Click="Add_Click">Add</Button>
</Grid>
```

TextBox labeled as "Selected Name" is only updated when I click the mouse outside the TextBoxes of the DataTemplate to the right. It does not react to clicking on the TextBox items which display the selected item of the ListBox.

How can I make the binding fire when I click on anywhere on one of the displayed ListBox items?

Comment: Your code works fine. If you click on an item in your listbox, the value of the selected item appears in the textbox. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want to see an immediate change in the "Selected Name" textbox, while editing the name in one of the listbox items, you need to define the update trigger for the "Name" binding: Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}". The other way round, e.g. changing the value in the textbox and seeing the selected listbox item updated, should work as is as soon as the textbox looses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an `ItemContainerStyle` that selects the `ListBoxItem` container when any of its child elements have the keyboard focus:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LBox" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0 0 0 3" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```